# How to ask users to allow third party cookies in javascript

Tags: cookies, third-party-cookies

I added some advertise sections on react webpage.
Of course it works well on Chrome browser.
But it didn't work on safari (Macbook + iPhone).
I noticed that 3rd party cookies were blocked by default on Mac.

I want to write script to ask users to allow 3rd party cookies on browser or system.
How can I do it?
FYI, I used react-cookie-consent, but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not allow third-party cookies at all.
https://javascript.info/cookie#appendix-third-party-cookies